# making modal for every entry in a list view using Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, cropperjs

I have a page where multiple images are present and I want to make the users able to crop any of them so I made a for loop to make a modal for each image and I looped the js function also.

this is my modal.

```
     {% for image in Patient_detail.images.all %}
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalCrop{{image.pk}}">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Crop the photo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="" id="image{{image.pk}}" style="max-width: 100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="btn-group pull-left" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-zoom-in">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-zoom-out">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Nevermind</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-crop-and-upload">Crop and upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    {% endfor %}
```

and here's the function I used

```
  {% for image in Patient_detail.images.all %}
 $(function () {

      /* SCRIPT TO OPEN THE MODAL WITH THE PREVIEW */
      $("#crop{{image.pk}}").click(function () {
            var img_src = document.getElementById("img{{image.pk}}").src
            $("#image{{image.pk}}").attr("src", img_src);
            $("#modalCrop{{imahge.pk}}").modal("show");
          }
      });

      /* SCRIPTS TO HANDLE THE CROPPER BOX */
      var $image = $("#image{{image.pk}}");
      var cropBoxData;
      var canvasData;
      $("#modalCrop{{image.pk}}").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        $image.cropper({
          viewMode: 1,
          aspectRatio: 1/1,
          minCropBoxWidth: 200,
          minCropBoxHeight: 200,
          ready: function () {
            $image.cropper("setCanvasData", canvasData);
            $image.cropper("setCropBoxData", cropBoxData);
          }
        });
      }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        cropBoxData = $image.cropper("getCropBoxData");
        canvasData = $image.cropper("getCanvasData");
        $image.cropper("destroy");
      });

      $(".js-zoom-in").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", 0.1);
      });

      $(".js-zoom-out").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", -0.1);
      });

      /* SCRIPT TO COLLECT THE DATA AND POST TO THE SERVER */
      $(".js-crop-and-upload").click(function () {
        var cropData = $image.cropper("getData");
        $("#id_x{{image.pk}}").val(cropData["x"]);
        $("#id_y{{image.pk}}").val(cropData["y"]);
        $("#id_height{{image.pk}}").val(cropData["height"]);
        $("#id_width{{image.pk}}").val(cropData["width"]);
        $("#formUpload{{image.pk}}").submit();
      });

    });
    {% endfor %}
```

but the problem is the modal never shows so I don't really get what's the problem ?
what should I do to make this work is the problem with the first function to show the modal is there easier way to do this all i want is the users to be able to specify a part of the image they want ?

Comment: you should not define function multiple times like that in a for loop (I'm assuming this is in a template file and thus in your browser you see multiple `$(function() ...` defined below each other). Define one function and parse the id (or another attribute you set on the modal) to determine which image is being clicked on.

Comment: so how can I make a script run for each image modal ( to grab the coordinates,  etc )

Comment: Use a class as selector instead of an id. Then your function will trigger regardless of which modal is being opened. Add an attribute (e.g. `data-img={{image.pk}}`) to all modals, grab that attribute when the modal is opened, and then you know which image is being opened (`$image = $("#image" + $this.attr('data-img'))`)

Comment: sorry but i can't really get how can this help me
i previously had to make a delete modal for the same images and I made the modal by the same concept the new thing in this modal is previewing the image which is pretty new to me.

Comment: you say the modal doesn't show up, but the code to make it show is triggered by a click on `$("#crop{{image.pk}}")` (`$(#crop1)` or `$(#crop2)`... in your document) which you don't show in your template. Check you HTML source in your dev tools, set a breakpoint inside the on.('click') function,